# Time efficiency of Introduction to Database

Tags: c, arrays, time

I have a code that requires me to do this thing :

> 1. Input size of array and testcases.
> 2. A character of Operatiion such as (I,A,D,Q) and elements of array.
>
> I : Adding an element into the array.
>   A : Will change data in the database to a new data that is not exist in
>   the database.
>   D : Delete data which has value X from database.
>   Q : Show all data that less than equal X from database.

```
Input :
<size of Array> <operations/testcase>
<I/A/D/Q> <elements of array with X value>
```

The example of input :

```
Input : 
6 4
3 2 3 1 5 6
I 7
D 6
A 3 5
Q 7

Output :
6 (because only 1 Q operation)
```

I already created the program, but I think this **is not  efficient enough** because it take a longer time to execute. My question is what should I do to make my program more efficient?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define MAXSIZE 99999

void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void printArr(int arr[]){
    for(int i = 0; arr[i] != NULL; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) 
{ 
    int i, j, k; 
    int n1 = m - l + 1; 
    int n2 = r - m; 
    int L[n1], R[n2]; 

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j]; 

    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
    { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
        { 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else
        { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 

    while (i < n1) 
    { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 

    while (j < n2) 
    { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
} 

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
{ 
    if (l < r) 
    { 
        int m = l+(r-l)/2; 
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r); 

        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
} 

int binarySearch(int arr[], int left, int right,int num){
    if(right >= left){
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if(num == arr[mid]) return mid;
        if(arr[mid] > num) return binarySearch(arr, left, mid-1, num);
        else return binarySearch(arr,mid+1,right, num);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int operations, sizeArr, numX, numY, arr[MAXSIZE];
    char type;

    scanf("%d %d",&sizeArr,&operations); getchar();
    int index = 0, counter = 0;
    for(index = 0; index < sizeArr; index++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[index]); getchar();
    }
    mergeSort(arr, 0, sizeArr - 1);

    int left = 0, deleted = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < operations; j++){
        scanf("%c",&type); getchar();

        if(type == 'I'){
            scanf("%d",&numX); getchar();
            arr[index++] = numX;
            sizeArr++;
        }

        else if(type == 'A'){
            scanf("%d %d",&numX, &numY); getchar();
            mergeSort(arr, 0, sizeArr - 1);
            for(int i = deleted; arr[i] != NULL ; i++){
                if(arr[i] == numX){
                    int old = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = numY;
                    if(arr[i + 1] != old) break;
                }
            }

        }
        else if(type == 'D'){
            scanf("%d",&numX); getchar();
            for(int i = 0; arr[i] != NULL ; i++){
                if(arr[i] == numX){
                    int old = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = -1;
                    deleted++;
                    if(arr[i + 1] != old) break;
                    // sizeArr--;    
                }
            }
            mergeSort(arr, 0, sizeArr - 1);
        }

        else if(type == 'Q'){
            scanf("%d",&numX); getchar();
            mergeSort(arr, 0, sizeArr - 1);
            // printArr(arr);
            for(int i = deleted; i < sizeArr ; i++){
                if(arr[i] <= numX && arr[i] > -1){ 
                    counter++;
                    // printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
                }
                else break;
            }
            printf("%d\n",counter);
            counter = 0;
        }
        // printf("Size Arr : %d\n", sizeArr);
        // printf("Deleted : %d\n",deleted);
        // printArr(arr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please tell me my mistake to my program more efficient on time limit?

They didn't mention the time limit duration. It only gives 5/10 testcase that correct. So I need to find another efficient way to make my code goes faster.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on codereview

Comment: Consider using a linked list as your base data structure. Deleting and adding are O(1) and modifying and displaying the data are O(n). In case of an array, Deleting, Modifying and Displaying operations are O(n), Note that the modify operation checks for all elements and is therefore O(n)

Comment: What is the time limit? What is your duration? I.e. how much more efficient do you need to get? Where is the time limit coming from? I ask because if you are actually asking about a challenge and got a TLE (time limit exceeded) rejection, then mentioning that might be helpful to give context. The requirements however read more like a homework assignment. In that cas have a look at the definition of the "optimization" tag ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info ) , it lists optimisation goals. The last listed goal might be more interesting in that case than time optimisation.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje You are quite right, the requirements are however clear on "array", aren't they?

Comment: @Yunnosch they didnt mention the time limit duration. It only gives 5/10 testcase that correct. So I need to find another efficient way to make my code goes faster

Comment: If you only get half the test cases correct, then you need to fix the logic, not the speed. If you ask about possible problems instead of speed you will get help with that. Some people here are amazingly good at "sniffing" for possibly failing test cases, even if you do not know which they are.

Comment: Adding a `mergeSort` in operations for Display and Delete is very inefficient. You should remove the sort and in Display, loop over all elements and print only those greater than the limit

Comment: I do not understand the "A" operation, I think I would want a second parameter in that case.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the additional information you gave in a comment, because I think that people should help you discuss more than time efficiency. Feel free to undo that, if you think that it is not what you want. Please accept my apology in that case.

Comment: (continuing my two-above comment) ... and the sample input agrees on two  parameters for "A". But their meaning is not clearly explained in the description. If your logic fails 5 test cases, then you could try to interpret the "A" differently than you did.